# Javascript Redirect with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-analytics, subdomain, subdirectory

I need help figuring out how to successfully redirect while including Analytics code.

- I have a subdomain setup http://buuf.fractalsystems.org
- The subdomain is actually just a subfolder http://fractalsystems.org/buuf
- I have an HTML file in that subfolder which redirects to https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Fractal%20Systems

The code for that redirect file:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function delayedRedirect(){
    window.location = "https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Fractal%20Systems"
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1234567-8']); <!--I have my real ID there-->
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', 3000)">
<h2>ADW.BuuF.Theme is no more! You will be redirected to new and better apps in 3 seconds.</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This works as a redirect only if I don't include my Analytics code. I've tried moving the code around with no change.

**QUESTION**
How can I add a redirect, of any kind, and still be able to track with Google Analytics?

I've tried PHP redirects with no success and am pretty sure htaccess redirects wont help although I'm open to suggestions.

The reason I'm using a JavaScript redirect is so I can continue to track with Google Analytics and also show a little message or make a custom page with the delay.

Thanks for any help. Doesn't have to be JS, please, any input is welcome if you know of a solution.

Comment: did you try using the [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) worked like a charm! Legacy FTW! Thanks, @Balexandre

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Fractal%20Systems">
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1234567-8']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>ADW.BuuF.Theme is no more! You will be redirected to new and better apps in 5 seconds.</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

RECAP: I am now able to redirect while tracking those redirects using Google Analytics!

Meta Refresh (Taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh))

Examples

Place inside  to refresh page after 5 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Redirect to http://example.com/ after 5 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
```

Redirect to http://example.com/ immediately:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

Comment: any ideas of how to redirect fast (and not 5s)?

Comment: @DS_web_developer This solution worked for me, you could try and simply change the `content=5` value to something else, but that isn't the most robust...you should use http://stackoverflow.com/a/8692588/805031

Answer (score 42):

Note: `_gaq.push` allows pushing of functions onto the queue. The following code should redirect after 250 milliseconds (to allow time for the tracking pixel) after the _trackPageview:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1234567-8']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = "https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Fractal%20Systems";
    }, 250);
});

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Comment: Perfect answer. You might add a simple text link to the redirect url in the body text, so that users without javascript can reach the redirect url. Additionally, the google reference doc with the section on pushing functions can be found here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#PushingFunctions

Comment: I'm not convinced you need a timeout - the request for the image should always go out before the redirect - it doesn't matter if the client never receives any data back

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Agreed that it's not important that the client never receives any data back, but it appears (at least with Chrome & Firefox) that the browser will not make the tracking pixel request if the window changes too quickly after the request is started. Google even has a note about using a delay, but their code is mucked up, mixing sync & async style analytics.

Comment: @mike Do you remember where you found the note about using delay from google?

Comment: Some people block GA so using a `<meta>` tag redirect as a fallback is a good idea.

Comment: I would love to see this answer updated to also include an answer with the new universal tracking code.

Answer (score 22):

If you're using the new GA code you can simply replace this line `ga('send', 'pageview');` with this code:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'hitCallback': function() {
      window.location = "http://www.your-site.com";
  }
});
```

Example in full:

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;
    i[r]=i[r]||function() {
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)
    },i[r].l=1*new Date();
    a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async=1;
    a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-2', 'auto');

ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'hitCallback': function() {
      window.location = "http://www.your-site.com";
  }
});
```

Comment: auto should be quoted

Answer (score 16):

I'd suggest changing your Google Analytics code to be synchronous instead of asychronous by changing it to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1234567-8']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
```

This should guarantee that it runs before your redirect code kicks in and it should be out of the way of your redirect script so there is no interference.  As you have it now, you're playing a guessing game for how long the GA script will take to load and that it will load and do it's job in under 3 seconds.  That may usually be the case, but there is no reason to load it asynchronously like you are and have to play that game.  Load it synchronously and it will do it's job before your javascript redirect fires.

It might even be possible to just put the redirect directly after the GA code like this and minimize the time that your placeholder page is displayed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1234567-8']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location = "https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Fractal%20Systems";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work with all redirect methods I've tried. Good to know.

Answer (score 9):

The [code provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8694071/1729516) by [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595070/mike) works indeed. However, I found that removing the timer entirely works as well. The __utm.gif request is then aborted, but all information has been sent. The window just redirects and doesn't wait for the reply (which is simply a 200 status). I tested this and it seems to be working nicely.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1234567-8']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(function() {
  window.location = "https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Fractal%20Systems";
});


(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Comment: This solution works beautifully...but if a user has JavaScript disabled, will GA not only not work, but the page won't redirect as well? Would it be best to have a `meta` redirect after this script, just in case?

Answer (score 2):

Meta refresh is generally discouraged because of usability concerns (especially with a short, or no delay), but as a **fallback** for clients with no javascript I think it's perfectly valid in this case.

If you **combine** the synchronous ga.js call with a meta refresh you get the best of both worlds: an almost instant, tracked redirect if JS is enabled; a delayed but still effective redirect if not (and a hard link in the body just in case all else fails).

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--For JS disabled: decent delay, both for usability and to allow plenty of time for JS to work if enabled -->
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Fractal%20Systems"/>
    <script>
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1234567-8']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    </script>
    <!--Synchronous call to ensure tracking fires before JS redirect-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
    <script>
        /* if JS is enabled this will normally fire well before the meta refresh delay ends: an almost instantaneous redirect */
        window.location="https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Fractal%20Systems";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Include a hard link in case both js and the meta refresh fail -->
    <p>Redirecting you to <a href="https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Fractal%20Systems">https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Fractal%20Systems</a></p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a good answer here:
https://www.domsammut.com/code/setting-up-hitcallback-using-google-universal-analytics

In short, you'd do it using an event, and you use the hitCallback function.

Answer (score 0):

This approach does not require a delay. First execute google analytics code synchronously and then redirect.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
  <script>
    var tracker = ga.create('UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
    tracker.send('pageview');
    window.location='http://your-url.com';
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think maybe just use jquery ready method so it won't start the timer till the page is fully loaded...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {       
    setTimeout(function() {
        //alert("redirecting!");
        window.location = '<?= $url ?>';
    }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Using jQuery in this case is way much overhead, and most of all, unnecessary.