# Google Analytics in a php redirect file

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have a php shorturl website like bitly and i want to track users accessing the short urls. Is there anyway i can get the google analytics code in here and working someone? just adding it wont work, the code will not run at all. I tried to add  above the code to make it work. The site is running php 7.3

```
<head>
                <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
                <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXX-1"></script>
                <script>
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                gtag('js', new Date());
</head>

    <?php
    require_once('master.php');
    
    if ($shortUrlObj->status != "active")
    {
        $errorMsg = t("longer_active");
        redirect(ROOT . "/404." . EXTENSION . "?e=" . urlencode($errorMsg));
    }
    
    $redirectType = SITE_CONFIG_REDIRECT_TYPE;
    
    switch ($redirectType)
    {
        default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily');
            redirect($Url->Url);    
        break;
    }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: You can add a delay before redirect so the Google Analytics can process the traffic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to track with Google Analytics on a redirection page with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453830/how-to-track-with-google-analytics-on-a-redirection-page-with-php)

Comment: how long of a delay must it be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add UTM parameters in the URL queryString, so you will be able to recognize the source and the medium. Something like this:

```
/your-page.php?utm_source=YOURSHORTURLWEBSITE&utm_medium=YOURSHORTURL
```

Where `YOURSHORTURLWEBSITE` could be the domain name of the site containing the *shorturls* and `YOURSHORTURL` the **shorturl** link.